# Ошибка при заполнении базы данных MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, sql-server

Используя функцию Insert хочу добавить данные в базу данных, но возникает следующая ошибка:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '№'.
```

Вот выполняемый код.

```
public void Insert(string num, string index, string fio, string city, string date)
    {
        string sql = string.Format("INSERT People_list" +
               "(№, Индекс, ФИО, Адрес, Дата) Values(@№, @Индекс, @ФИО, @Адрес, @Дата)");

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, this.connect))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@№", num);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Индекс", index);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ФИО", fio);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Адрес", city);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Дата", date);

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException odbcEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Возникли проблемы с функцией Insert = " + odbcEx);
            }
        }
}
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
string sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO People_list" +
           "([№], [Индекс], [ФИО], [Адрес], [Дата]) Values(@id, @zip, @name, @address, @date)");

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, this.connect))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", num);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", index);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", fio);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", city);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException odbcEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Возникли проблемы с функцией Insert = " + odbcEx);
    }
}
```

Но вообще использовать кириллицу для идентификаторов это не самая лучшая идея.

Comment: Так тоже не работает, та же ошибка.

Comment: Обновил ответ, уменьшил использование кириллицы до минимума. Там ещё ```INTO``` было пропущено.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось!